# In this code, why is the second loop executing slower than the first one?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, execution-time

I have this code in Java, using two different types of loops.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long fl = 0, wl = 0; 
        int i = 0;
        int a = 0;
        long start = 0, stop = 0;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(i<2000000000){
             if(i%2 == 0)
                a++;
            else
                a--;
            i++;
        }
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        wl = stop-start/2;
        System.out.println("\nWhile loop = "+wl);

        i = 0;
        a = 0;
        start = 0;
        stop = 0;

        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(;i<2000000000;){
            if(i%2 == 0)
                a++;
            else
                a--;
            i++;
        }
        stop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fl = stop-start/2;
        System.out.println("For loop = "+fl);

        System.out.println("Difference = "+(fl-wl));
    }
}
```

Now, after running the program multiple times, I have come to the conclusion that the second loop is always executing slower than the first loop. At first, I thought it had something to do with one being a for loop and the other being a while loop, but even when I reversed the order, the second loop still executes slower. Here is the output of a sample run.

```
While loop = 688721817947
For loop = 688721824295
Difference = 6348
```

Now, why is this happening.

Comment: Would you really like to try explaining a difference that is less than `0.000001%`?

Answer (score 6):

You calculate your time based on

```
fl = stop-start/2;
```

due to [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

```
fl = stop - (start / 2)
```

That's not what you want I guess, as executing it 100 ms later would cause your `fl` variable to be 50ms "longer" (`(stop + 100) - ((start + 100) / 2) = stop - (start / 2) + 50`). That could be a reason why the second one is always "slower".

Comment: 688721817947 milliseconds is over 20 years, making the original output obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A difference *that* small is really negligible, and it's difficult if not impossible to determine what caused it. The bytecode of your two loops is identical:

**`while`-loop:**

```
  21: goto          43
  24: iload         5
  26: iconst_2      
  27: irem          
  28: ifne          37
  31: iinc          6, 1
  34: goto          40
  37: iinc          6, -1
  40: iinc          5, 1
  43: iload         5
  45: ldc           #22                 // int 2000000000
  47: if_icmplt     24
```

**`for`-loop:**

```
 104: goto          126
 107: iload         5
 109: iconst_2      
 110: irem          
 111: ifne          120
 114: iinc          6, 1
 117: goto          123
 120: iinc          6, -1
 123: iinc          5, 1
 126: iload         5
 128: ldc           #22                 // int 2000000000
 130: if_icmplt     107
```

Answer (score 0):

That difference has no sense, as `6348 / 688721824295` aprox 9-E9. That is, less than a 1-E6 %.

Anything could cause the difference, from the OS processing a thread from another process or the antivirus kicking it or a cosmic ray causing interference. It is like asking why car A makes a route in 1 hour and another makes it in 1 hour and 1 millionth of a second.